# using tee to output intermediate results to stdout instead of files

Tags: bash, command-line, tee

I know that to capture a pipeline's contents at an intermediate stage of processing, we use tee as `ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | tee abc.txt | grep out` , but what if i don't want to redirect the **contents after uniq to abc.txt** *but* **to screen**(through stdout, ofcourse) so that as an end result , **i'll have on screen, the intermediate contents after uniq as well as the contents after grep.**

Comment: The problem is `stdout` is a pipe to `grep out`. It's not your terminal anymore. Do you have any sort of guarantee that this will **always** be run from a terminal?

Comment: @JoeSewell In my case, yes from a terminal, but please tell what are the other sources from apart from terminal(are you talking about simply shell-scripting or something else). Just curious. I'm new to Linux and would love to explore what you are talking in detail.

Comment: One of my comments to an answer below gives a few examples. Running it from within `gvim` may leave you without a terminal at all. Having this line in a `gmake` makefile may cause problems if the `-j` option is used, and the subshell in use doesn't have access to the terminal. `cron` jobs wouldn't have a terminal, either. A shell script, on the other hand, **might** have a terminal, unless it's run without one.

Comment: @JoeSewell thanks, i'll do some research on them :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

sometimes /dev/tty can be used for that...

```
ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | tee /dev/tty | grep out | wc
```

Comment: This assumes the command is run from a terminal.

Comment: `ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | tee /dev/tty | grep out | wc > out` only contains the output from `wc`.

Comment: @user7543 tee -o out will give you tee output you can dan do wc >> out to append output to the file (depending on nonglobering settings that is). I would use file descriptor for both tee and grep and cat it.

Comment: On Linux at least you can also use `tee /dev/stdout`.

Comment: @Mike, tee /dev/stdout is fine but it would duplicate the files that "enter" the `grep out` command (wc numbers would be the double)

Answer (score 12):

```
ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | tee /dev/fd/2 | grep out | wc
```

On a linux system you can use the the `/dev/fd/[num]` links like named pipes in many cases. This will duplicate stdout to stderr, which, typically, is your terminal *screen*, but doesn't need to be.

Comment: Only works with bash, not dash /bin/sh on Ubuntu. I use this command for docker build: `ID=$(docker build "$dockercontext" 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/3 - | tail -1)`

Comment: @DanielAlder - it works fine with `dash`. but you need to direct it somewhere. where does `&3` go? the `fd/2` above assumes the command is run from a terminal and `&2` goes to the `tty`. for example: `dash -c '{ echo hey; read v; echo "${v#?}" >/dev/fd/2; } <>/dev/fd/1 |:'`

Comment: You are right. Didn't realize that /dev/fd/* are now also supported in dash. fd/3 is redirected to stdout in my case. I use this command line now, the other variant was overkill: `ID=$(docker build "$1" 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/2 - | tail -1)`

Comment: @DanielAlder - those dont really have anything to do with the shell. theyre just files. or... links to file-descriptors anyway. but the shell doesnt put them there or control their behavior at all - those are handled by the kernel. the shell just does `open()` and `dup2()` with file-descriptors and it treats those exactly the same as it does any other file.

Comment: You don't know the history, and I didn't know the current situation. Not many years ago, there was no /dev/fd/ in the system. It was compiled directly in bash like /dev/tcp/ too which can be used to open tcp connections. Actually, bash still supports the emulation in case it can't find /dev/fd. Obviously I missed some developments of /proc/self, udev and the kernel so I didn't know that this is now system default.

Comment: @DanielAlder - it was `ksh`, actually, not `bash` that started all that - especially the `/dev/tcp` socket biz.  in fact `|` isnt even a pipe at all in `ksh` - its a socket, and `/dev/fd/[anything]` fails for it. guess they came full circle.

Answer (score 3):

```
mkfifo myfifo
cat myfifo& ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | tee myfifo | grep out
```

`mkfifo` creates a FIFO (first in, first out) special file, a.k.a. a named pipe. 
Start an asynchronous `cat` to read from the fifo, and then run your pipeline,
`tee`ing the intermediate result to the fifo.

This will produce a `[1]+  Done            cat myfifo` message at the end. 
You can suppress that with this magic trick:

```
(cat myfifo&); ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | tee myfifo | grep out
```

For a long term, robust solution, you might want to create a permanent fifo
(e.g., `$HOME/myfifo`) rather than creating a new one every time. 
But that will fail if you may be running multiple instances of this simultaneously. 
Alternatively,

- Generate a unique name (e.g., with `mktemp`).
- Create the fifo in a directory that's guaranteed to be writable (e.g., `/tmp`).
- Remove the fifo at the end of the command.

Answer (score 3):

How to do it (example):

```bsh
exec 3>&1; ( ls |( tee >&3 ) >/dev/null ); exec 3>&-
```

Which will show the ls result **and** send it to nirvanah.

To grok the key part, `3>&1`, you may read [I/O Redirection](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) and esp. this [example](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html#REDIR1).

In short: `>somefile`is short for `1>somefile`, which in turn means *Assign the file handle of somefile to file descriptor 1 (and drop the former value of that descriptor, for the scope of this process)*.

So, `3>&1` means: *Assign the file descriptor 1 (which may but need not be tty) to the (until now unused) file descriptor 3*. We're effectively using `&3` as a temporary variable.

Comment: The exact command provided doesn't work for me:
`$ 3>&1 ls |( tee >&3 ) >/dev/null` gives 
`bash: 3: Bad file descriptor`

Comment: Thanks @ColinPitrat, i seem to have missed something, but using exec it works for me.

Comment: Cool, this makes it a great answer because it's now more portable and conceptually simpler than all the others.

Answer (score 2):

This command worked for me.

```
ls /bin /usr/bin | sort | uniq | tee /dev/pts/0 | grep out
```

You could check what is your terminal using the command `tty` and replace the tee to redirect the output to that terminal.

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18025293/1742825

Comment: That assumes the command runs on the terminal /dev/pts/0.

Comment: @JoeSewell, you could see which is the running terminal using `tty`. I have updated with that information.

Comment: Nice update, but why not use `/dev/tty` instead? That assumes, of course, that the command even has access to the terminal. If it's run from, for example, inside `gvim`, there may be no terminal involved at all. Doing this within `gmake` could become even more complex with multiple jobs, since not all processes can get to "the terminal."

Comment: Or use the output of the `tty` command? `tee \`tty\`` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the case this is being run from a terminal you could

- start a terminal multiplexer such as tmux or screen
- split your terminal - in tmux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>
- in the first window `touch abc.txt` then `tail -f abc.txt`
- switch to the second window and run your command. You'll see the file created by tee update.

Answer (score -2):

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

```
cat stuff | 3>&1 tee 3 | xsel -i
```

Edit: unfortunately, the above ↑ is incorrect.
An earlier answer of

```
cat stuff  | tee >(cat) | xsel -i
```

is good though.

Comment: (1) It seems to me that this does not do what the question asks for.  (2) TLDP is not a good source of information; please do not use it.  (3) I don’t see much correlation between the page you linked to and your answer.  Why are you giving TLDP credit (/ blame)?  (4) The question is about a pipeline involving `ls`, `sort`, `uniq` and `grep`.  It’s good manners to answer the question that was asked — and yet your answer shows a pipeline involving `cat` (a UUOC, BTW) and `xsel`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (5) Please don’t clutter our site with answers that you know to be wrong, unless you have a good reason to do so.  Instead of *adding* a second answer (and, inexplicably, calling it an “earlier answer”), just delete the wrong answer and replace it with the one that’s less bad.