# How to print and use a command output in a one-liner?

Tags: bash, command-line, subshell

I'd like to pass the result of `mktemp` as argument to a command, let's say `gcc -o`. `gcc -o $(mktemp)` causes the result to be used, but I need to figure out the result.

The only thing I could come up with is `gcc -o $(out=$(mktemp); echo $out)`, but that doesn't print the value to console, but instead it's used as argument value which is correct afaik.

Is there any way to get the result of `mktemp` printed to console.

I'm capable to solve this in a script. I'd like to broaden my knowledge with the one-liner solution you hopefully propose.

I'd like to use this in `bash` on Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about `tee` with `/dev/tty`?

```
$ gcc -o $(mktemp | tee /dev/tty) hello.c
/tmp/tmp.UBSSnulNn2

$ /tmp/tmp.UBSSnulNn2
Hello, world!
```

Related:

- [using tee to output intermediate results to stdout instead of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178752/using-tee-to-output-intermediate-results-to-stdout-instead-of-files)

Answer (score 8):

Switching things around in `gcc -o $(out=$(mktemp); echo $out)`:

```
out=$(mktemp); echo "$out"; gcc -o "$out" hello.c
```

... which also conveniently leaves the path in the variable for later uses. (Presumably you don't want to just see the path in the output to admire the beauty of `mktemp`'s random name generation, right? You want that path to use it elsewhere.)

Comment: Specifically, it might be a useful idea to `rm -f "$out"` afterwards.